# After upgrading Umbraco to 7.10.4 from 7.5.12 it asks to upgrade again and again

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Originally I've asked the question here on [our umbraco](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started//92444-after-upgrading-umbraco-asks-to-upgrade-again-on-azure-to-the-same-version)

I have no clue what is happening. 
I've updated my dev database/environment on my machine and it is working fine. Then I've published my code to Azure pointing to the same DB. The upgrade page is showing up :| and I don't understand why. It is saying that it wants to upgrade to the same version.

[image: asking for update]

[image: Umbraco migrations]

### Update

After clicking continue, it just shows that update is done and goes to the back office without any problem. Then I tried to access the web nodes (I have [Flexible load balancing settings](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/setup/server-setup/load-balancing/flexible)) and it asked me to upgrade again! :|

I tried republishing the whole site again, but didn't help either. I know I can click update here but ~/umbraco is closed in production for the web nodes as it is the best practice.

### Update 2

I've changed some small things and published again on back office. I've been redirected to AuthorizeUpgrade **again** :O

### Update 3

Also I have this line in my logs as if it is trying to upgrade but to a lower version number

```
Umbraco.Core.Configuration.ClientDependencyConfiguration - Updated version number from 1918068003 to 478377040
```

I've found this on my temp/install/[machinename] after auturizing for update (before clicking on continue button that does the upgrading)

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Permissions",
    "ServerOrder": 0,
    "IsComplete": false,
    "AdditionalData": {

    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Upgrade",
    "ServerOrder": 1,
    "IsComplete": false,
    "AdditionalData": {

    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "MajorVersion7UpgradeReport",
    "ServerOrder": 1,
    "IsComplete": false,
    "AdditionalData": {

    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Version73FileCleanup",
    "ServerOrder": 2,
    "IsComplete": false,
    "AdditionalData": {

    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "DatabaseInstall",
    "ServerOrder": 11,
    "IsComplete": false,
    "AdditionalData": {

    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "DatabaseUpgrade",
    "ServerOrder": 12,
    "IsComplete": false,
    "AdditionalData": {

    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "UmbracoVersion",
    "ServerOrder": 50,
    "IsComplete": false,
    "AdditionalData": {

    }
  }
]
```

Then I have updates in the log file:

```
 2018-06-13 13:32:46,081 [P7300/D15/T73] INFO  Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController - Executing installation step: Permissions
 2018-06-13 13:32:46,175 [P7300/D15/T73] INFO  Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController - Step completed (took 85ms)
 2018-06-13 13:32:46,268 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController - Executing installation step: Upgrade
 2018-06-13 13:32:46,286 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController - Step completed (took 26ms)
 2018-06-13 13:32:46,427 [P7300/D15/T73] INFO  Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController - Executing installation step: DatabaseInstall
 2018-06-13 13:32:46,458 [P7300/D15/T73] INFO  Umbraco.Core.DatabaseContext - Database configuration status: Started
 2018-06-13 13:32:46,458 [P7300/D15/T73] INFO  Umbraco.Core.DatabaseContext - Database requires upgrade
 2018-06-13 13:32:46,471 [P7300/D15/T73] INFO  Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController - Step completed (took 33ms)
 2018-06-13 13:32:46,534 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController - Executing installation step: DatabaseUpgrade
 2018-06-13 13:32:46,534 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Web.Install.InstallSteps.DatabaseUpgradeStep - Running 'Upgrade' service
 2018-06-13 13:32:46,566 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.DatabaseContext - Database upgrade started
 2018-06-13 13:32:46,706 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Initializing database migrations
 2018-06-13 13:32:46,724 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - Resolving umbraco.interfaces.IDiscoverable
 2018-06-13 13:32:46,724 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - Resolved umbraco.interfaces.IDiscoverable (took 4ms)
 2018-06-13 13:32:46,738 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - Resolving Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.IMigration
 2018-06-13 13:32:46,799 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - Resolved Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.IMigration (took 55ms)
 2018-06-13 13:32:46,993 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'AddIndexesToUmbracoRelationTables' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:47,065 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'AddIndexToUmbracoNodePath' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:47,143 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'AddIndexToUser2NodePermission' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:47,224 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'AddRelationTypeUniqueIdColumn' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:47,318 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'AddMacroUniqueIdColumn' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:47,334 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'NormalizeTemplateGuids' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:47,443 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'UpdateUniqueIndexOnCmsPropertyData' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:47,521 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'RemoveUmbracoDeployTables' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:47,521 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'ReduceLoginNameColumnsSize' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:47,521 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'AddIndexToCmsMemberLoginName' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:47,599 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'AddLockTable' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:47,599 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'AddLockObjects' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:47,678 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'UpdateUserTables' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:47,928 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'AddUserGroupTables' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:48,006 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'AddUserStartNodeTable' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:48,006 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'ReduceDictionaryKeyColumnsSize' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:48,021 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'AddIndexToDictionaryKeyColumn' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:48,021 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'EnsureContentTemplatePermissions' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:48,037 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'AddIndexToPropertyTypeAliasColumn' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:48,115 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'AddTourDataUserColumn' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:48,178 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'AddCmsMediaTable' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:48,256 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'AddInstructionCountColumn' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:48,334 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'AddUserLoginTable' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:48,396 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'AddUmbracoAuditTable' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:48,459 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'AddUmbracoConsentTable' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:48,537 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'AddIsSensitiveMemberTypeColumn' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:48,553 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'CreateSensitiveDataUserGroup' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:48,553 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Persistence.Migrations.MigrationRunner - Added UPGRADE migration 'RenamePreviewFolder' to context
 2018-06-13 13:32:49,297 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Core.DatabaseContext - Database configuration status: <p>Upgrade completed!</p>
 2018-06-13 13:32:49,316 [P7300/D15/T36] INFO  Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController - Step completed (took 2782ms)
 2018-06-13 13:32:49,375 [P7300/D15/T73] INFO  Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController - Executing installation step: UmbracoVersion
 2018-06-13 13:32:49,563 [P7300/D15/T73] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - Resolving umbraco.interfaces.IDiscoverable
 2018-06-13 13:32:49,585 [P7300/D15/T73] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - Resolved umbraco.interfaces.IDiscoverable (took 9ms)
 2018-06-13 13:32:49,585 [P7300/D15/T73] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - Resolving umbraco.interfaces.ICacheRefresher
 2018-06-13 13:32:49,585 [P7300/D15/T73] INFO  Umbraco.Core.PluginManager - Resolved umbraco.interfaces.ICacheRefresher (took 10ms)
 2018-06-13 13:32:49,789 [P7300/D15/T73] INFO  umbraco.content - Load Xml from file...
 2018-06-13 13:32:49,868 [P7300/D15/T73] INFO  umbraco.content - Loaded Xml from file.
 2018-06-13 13:32:49,882 [P7300/D15/T73] INFO  umbraco.content - Loading content from database...
 2018-06-13 13:32:51,749 [P7300/D15/T73] INFO  Umbraco.Web.Install.Controllers.InstallApiController - Step completed (took 2386ms)
```

### Update 4

After going through updates the site starts working but then every time I publish my source code the same thing (update process) happens again :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `web.config` you will see a line: `<add key="umbracoConfigurationStatus" value="7.x.x" />`.

This line is what version Umbraco currently think it is running as. It is used to determine (along with the version of the DLL) if an upgrade should be run.

You need to check if your build scripts or maybe some transformations are copying an old `web.config`, or maybe modifying the file during the builds, to have an "old" version number instead of the one that should usually be there after running an upgrade.

It does however sound a bit weird that it wants to upgrade from the same version as the one it wants to upgrade to... but try what I mentioned above and see if that gives you some clues as to what might be happening.

The database table you mention is used to keep track of which migrations have been run between various upgrades.

Comment: Thanks,that was it. For some strange  reason there was a config transform for umbracoConfigurationStatus which caused the whole issue

Comment: No problem - happy you got it sorted!